# Mapping USB keyboard Fn key to Option key with DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I have this usb keyboard and macOS 10.14.6. :

[image]

I'm using the file [`DefaultKeyBinding.dict`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229509/apple-keyboard-remap-keypad-comma-to-dot) to remap several keys on a MacBook Pro. Is there a way to specify that my right <kbd>Fn</kbd> key has to be bound to the <kbd>Option</kbd>  key.

I need this since I'm trying to have an <kbd>Option</kbd> key on the bottom right zone of the USB keyboard, mimicking the MacBook Pro  keyboard.

I'd prefer not to use external tools.

I don't find Modifier keys settings helpful for function keys:

[image]

Using Karabiner event, it seems like keystrokes on <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are not detected by the Mac. Can I fix it?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331519/313842 https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228853/313842 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94932/313842

Comment: thank you @ankii once again. Looks like this keyboard is not sending any signal to the mac when i press FN keys. Karabiner's Event Viewer does not detect anything. Nothing to do. :(

Comment: Further info here: https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/999

Comment: Doesn’t the Alt Gr key work like option for your purposes?

Comment: Hi @TomGewecke! Yes it does. But I remapped Alt (and Alt Gr) and Windows keys to have the same sequence of keys of a macbook keyboard (e.g., http://osxdaily.com/2018/01/31/use-windows-pc-keyboard-mac-remap-option-command-keys/). Consequently, Fn should "become" option. Looks like it's not possible :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using Karabiner event, it seems like keystrokes on <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are not detected by the Mac. Can I fix it?

**You can’t remap the Fn key as it’s an *internal* keyboard modifier and not sent to the OS**

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331519/119271) from a similar question for full details.

Basically, if a scan code isn’t sent by the keyboard to be received by the OS (and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> code isn’t), nothing can be remapped.

Comment: This is wrong. MacOS does detect fn key standalone. In order to test it go to Assessbility>Keyboard>Enable Sticky Keys. Then press fn key.

Comment: Yes. In fact, there's an option that allows the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to be used to switch the input source. Karabiner EventViewer also detects <kbd>fn</kbd> being pressed.