# Logitech MK850 Macbook pro Catalina Fn key

Tags: keyboard, catalina

Recently bought a [Logitech MK850](https://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/mk850-wireless-keyboard-mouse-combo). It has `Ctrl`, `Fn`, `Opt`, `Cmd` buttons on the left. I'm trying to switch the `Ctrl` and `Fn` keys so that it's the same as the Macbook keyboard (which has `Fn` then `Ctrl`). Tried the Keyboard preferences but no luck - it doesn't seem to let me modify the `Fn` keys. Any idea how to map keys? (FWIW: recently switched to Mac and trying to get used to the new key layout)
[image]

Comment: This is not possible. Fn combines with its 'partner' key before ever leaving the keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping USB keyboard Fn key to Option key with DefaultKeyBinding.dict](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379846/mapping-usb-keyboard-fn-key-to-option-key-with-defaultkeybinding-dict) Also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331514/use-f1-f2-etc-keys-to-control-built-in-mac-features-when-using-an-external-usb

Comment: To confuse you still further [sorry ;) the Fn key on an extended Apple keyboard isn't down to the left like on a laptop, it's where Windows has the Insert key. See https://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/mx-keys-mac-wireless-keyboard.920-009560.html

Comment: Oh well.. that's really annoying...